# How to pass a token to views that require authentication in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an app that stores users and their posts. To view the page of a user, I want it to require authentication for a given user. I'm not quite sure how to implement this because before without DRF, I'd just check if the current user was the same as the id requested in the url like page/users/10. DRF generates tokens for each user which I have specified when they register with this:

```
class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        "token": Token.objects.get(user=user).key
        })
```

Each token keys to a user like here:
[image]
What I am wondering is how can I get each of these tokens to be used to authenticate the user. If the user logs in with his account, how will I be able to get the token and then pass it to the restricted views?

Here is one of the views that restricts access to only logged in users:

```
class CreateGroupView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    # meeting_link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        self.request.session.create()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            owner = User.objects.get(id=serializer.data.get('owner'))
            name = serializer.data.get('name')
            description = serializer.data.get('description')
            meeting_link = serializer.data.get('meeting_link')
            group = Group(owner=owner, description=description, meeting_link=meeting_link, name=name)
            group.save()
            return Response(GroupSerializer(course).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Here are some of my url patterns to show what I am working with

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('viewgroup', views.GroupView.as_view()),
    path('creategroup', views.CreateGroupView.as_view()),
    path('register', views.RegisterView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: I guess you should figure  out JWT mechanism first.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to return the token to the user when they successfully login to their account and save that token in the `localstorage` of that user.

Now that the user has access to the `token` pass it as `Authorization HTTP header` like this:

```
Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b
```

Now when you request the url

```
fetch(YOUR_URL, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {Accept: 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': 'Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'}
});
```

And now in your view you can simply access the user as `request.user`.

You can read more at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: How do I pass the token as the http header? I have a view model for the pages that are restricted so do I need to pass it as I am entering the view?

Comment: Yes you need to pass it as you enter the view via a GET/POST request

Comment: The way my app works is that I take a view like generics.APIview and then I use that to take my serializer and turn it into a sort of form.  In my urls.py file, I pass the as_view() to the desired path. I'm not quite sure how I am supposed to pass the token as I am visiting the api as view

Comment: You need to understand how an API works. You send an API request to your route and that route(view) returns a JSON response. I have edited my answer to show how to make an API call to your desired view. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I added my urls and the restricted code. I see the fetch request and I'm thinking that Is what I can use on my frontend app to get the data. However, these views I have made are sort of letting me make requests with a graphical interface. I think I will have to somehow enter in the headers as I am viewing the api/creategroup page to see it.